# Multiple Azure Sql Databases with one Web App Instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-server

Hi I'm working on an application that has 200+ SQL Azure databases and one Web App instance.

The web application is frequently calling all these databases depending on the request (only one database connection is used per request).

The problem we have seen lately is that timeouts/other connectivity issues is happening more frequently.

I'm starting to think that it could be all the tcp/connections that needs to be maintained by the connection pool. Because of Azure SQL there will be one database connection per database in the pool, they can't share connection.

Is my assumption correct or could there be anything else?

Comment: Might be just normal transient errors.  Do you have any retry logic in your code?

Comment: Are you capturing the specifics errors?

Comment: We are using the Sql Azure Transient Strategy that Entity Framework 6 are having, we have extended it with error code 4060 which happens alot, and even if we are using the strategy it's still failing after 5 retries which usually means at least a total wait time of 40 secconds. Other exceptions is non transient ones like -1 and and Win32Exception's